# Think of a better method name or create separate functions for a possible single responsibility?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I'm still currently learning OOP. I need a method that takes in a `List<JsonNode>`. Now there are multiple components that need some resources from the List. `Component1` needs *all* of the keys. `Component2` only needs the keys that have a *numerical value*. As we understand, these two both need keys, thus requiring a function to iterate through the given `List` and ***parse*** the keys from the given `List`.

What we are planning is that all of it happens in a single function/class (or rather as a single responsibility). This `responsible function` would take in a `List instance`, iterate through the List and one by one get the keys and create a *resource* for `Component1`; while it does so, it also looks for the keys with numerical values and creates a *resource* for `Component2`. The name of the responsibility would be `Extractor`.

Would this be in accordance with OOP principles? Should we just give it a better definition(name)? Or should we define them as two different responsibilities?

***Edit***:

So JsonNode has keys and they're all different from each other. I may have

```
[{"name":"john", "age": 10, "status":"single"}]
```

So I need to get

```
Component1 -> [name, age, status]
Component2 -> [age]
```

Comment: The part I'm getting a little stuck on is why you have to parse keys in the map (not saying you don't have a genuine reason, I'm just having a hard time trying to imagine one).

Comment: I simply need to get all the keys in the map and the map may also have Maps as values meaning there will be nested keys. Let's just say that we need those keys as a resource - like options. I'll be editing above as i forgot to include something.

Comment: I was planning to migrate to Map but then realize it may be harder to implement. Sorry but what we're currently using is List<JsonNode>. So I changed the content above.

Comment: What you name things has little to do with OOP principles, though a vague or overly long name could be a potential sign of OOP trouble.

Comment: What I was thinking about the name was being specific with it. I can choose to name the function for `Component1` as ***`AllKeysParser`*** and function for `Component2` as ***`NumericalValueKeyParser`***. But if I choose to combine them then it could be just `KeyExtractor`

Comment: So much effort naming methods a none at all for giving a meaningful name to the "components". The component's (classes) name also matters because the names of the methods are going to be subordinated (semantically) to the class name.

Comment: What you describe here is typically a part of some JSON mapping framework that (based on some configuration) parses a JSON node to an object with the correct data in the corresponding fields. Are you writing your own JSON / object mapper or what's the reason behind doing the parsing by hand?

Comment: Component1 and Component2 are the ones requesting for data. Component1 _needs_ all the keys and Component2 _needs_ keys with numerical value. That's all there is to it. What I'm asking is if it would be better to separate the functions or lump them together.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff yes. it's typically a part of some json mapping framework. No, i'm not writing my own object mapper. It's not that I'm doing it by hand. Clean code suggests that functions should be doing one thing and do what they're name suggests. If i was to gather the keys for component 1 and the numeric keys for component 2, then put them together in a function `GetKeys`, I'd be violating Clean code policy. So I just want to know if it would be better to separate them or not.

Comment: Since function1 (get all keys) and function2 (get numerical valued keys) all receive the same object and return the same object, I was thinking to make an interface for the two of them and create them as separate components. But I was unsure if that was the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

> What we are planning is that all of it happens in a single function/class (or rather as a single responsibility).

I can't say I've ever *planned* a responsibility. I find that I plan behavior and the responsibilities emerge as that behavior is assigned or implemented.

In your case, the planned behavior is that the two components will receive keys where the values meet certain conditions from a given set of JSON objects. The initial objects we have are the components, the JSON values, and some new behavior that will cover the rest. The simplest implementation (assuming some details of how it would work):

```
void extractKeysForComponents(List<JsonValue> jsonValues, Component component1, Component component2) {
    jsonValues.stream()
        .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
        .forEach((key) -> component1.add(key));

    jsonValues.stream()
        .filter((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.value() instanceof Number)
        .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
        .forEach((key) -> component2.add(key));
}
```

Our simplest implementation implements the behavior we want. Of course we also wrote tests for this (which I will just assume are there). This method is very smelly though. The method takes two `Component` parameters that do not interact. This is the first indication that we are doing more than one thing. The implementation has two clearly distinct parts. This is the second indication. Those two parts are also near-duplicates. This is our third indication. At this point, we can see that there might be more than one responsibility hiding in there, but what they are has not yet emerged. We know duplication is the worst of the three indicators we have, but we only have *near*-duplication. Let's make them as similar as possible:

```
void extractKeysForComponents(List<JsonValue> jsonValues, Component component1, Component component2) {
    jsonValues.stream()
        .filter((jsonValue) -> true)
        .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
        .forEach((key) -> component1.add(key));

    jsonValues.stream()
        .filter((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.value() instanceof Number)
        .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
        .forEach((key) -> component2.add(key));
}
```

Now both parts are as similar as we can make them while still preserving behavior. Fixing the near-duplication also points us to a potential responsibility: filtering. Before, we had a hidden default filter of no filter. Now, that's become explicit. Let's pull out what varies so we can begin to encapsulate it:

```
void extractKeysForComponents(List<JsonValue> jsonValues, Component component1, Component component2) {
    Predicate<JsonValue> component1Filter = (jsonValue) -> true;
    Predicate<JsonValue> component2Filter = (jsonValue) -> jsonValue.value() instanceof Number;

    jsonValues.stream()
        .filter(component1Filter)
        .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
        .forEach((key) -> component1.add(key));

    jsonValues.stream()
        .filter(component2Filter)
        .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
        .forEach((key) -> component2.add(key));
}
```

Now we see that the only difference between the duplicated parts is which component and associated filter are used. Maybe we can use a data structure to associate those two components to their filters in a generic way:

```
void extractKeysForComponents(List<JsonValue> jsonValues, Component component1, Component component2) {
    Map<Component, Predicate<JsonValue> componentsAndPredicates = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    componentsAndPredicates.put(component1, (jsonValue) -> true);
    componentsAndPredicates.put(component2, (jsonValue) -> jsonValue.value() instanceof Number);

    for (Map.Entry<Component, Predicate<JsonValue>> entry : componentsAndPredicates) {
        jsonValues.stream()
            .filter(entry.getValue())
            .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
            .forEach((key) -> entry.getKey().add(key));
    }
}
```

Now separate responsibilities are more clearly starting to emerge. `Component`s are associated with specific filters, so perhaps we should move those filters over to the `Component` classes? Each component can then provide its filter in a generic way. (This is one way to approach this problem, and there are others. I am simply choosing this one since I don't have enough details about your specific code.) The code would look like:

```
void extractKeysForComponents(List<JsonValue> jsonValues, Component component1, Component component2) {
    List<Component> components = Arrays.asList(component1, component2);

    for (Component component : components) {
        jsonValues.stream()
            .filter(component.getJsonValueFilter())
            .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
            .forEach((key) -> component.add(key));
    }
}
```

What is now most strange is that we are taking just two `Component` parameters to convert them to a list and handle them generically. In programming, there are only three numbers: [zero, one, and many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule). We can take an arbitrary number of `Component`s and handle them all equally well.

```
void extractKeysForComponents(List<JsonValue> jsonValues, Component... components) {
    for (Component component : components) {
        jsonValues.stream()
            .filter(component.getJsonValueFilter())
            .map((jsonValue) -> jsonValue.key())
            .forEach((key) -> component.add(key));
    }
}
```

So we've gone from an implementation that supported very specific behavior to one that can handle arbitrary behavior in a more generic way, while progressively exposing responsibilities. We didn't plan the responsibilities, though. We just followed where the code and refactorings led us. There's still a lot to do with this code. I still don't think the responsibilities are properly distributed. There are a number of bad names. There were alternate refactorings that could have been better. But we've started on a path to revealing those responsibilities without needing to identify or design them all up front.